# spring mvc controller equivallent javaee controller

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I used spring.

Is there an equivalent controller strategy for pure plain java-ee 6/7?
Like there is spring controllers which take care of path params, request params, return types, redirecting, redirecting to views with a modelAndView object to carry data?

```
@Controller
class MyControllerClass {

      @RequestMapping...
      method(){
         ServiceCall()...
      //put something to modelAndView object here and redirect to jsp page.
      return "home"; // this will redirect data to home.jsp

      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to use the Jersey implementation of [JAX-RS](https://jersey.java.net/).

The controller would look like:

```
@Path("same_as_the_class_request_mapping")
public class MyControllerClass{

    @Path("pretty_much_same_as_the_method_request_mapping")
    @GET //or whatever you need
    public Viewable roaster(){
        //do whatever
        return new Viewable("home", some_model_object);
    }
}
```

You can see more information [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html) and a good tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).

Jersey also gives you the ability to integrate with Spring, thus enabling one to call Spring services from Jersey controllers. Check out [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) for more details

Comment: will this controller be a servlet? how can I know?

Comment: No, it is not a Servlet. The idea is pretty much the same as a Spring MVC controller. There is no need to drop down to Servlets. Jersey does most of the things you need just like Spring MVC does most of the things you need without having to use Servlets

Comment: so its a `servlet thread` under the hood? Just like a normal servlet? 2) how to deal the id in both, request or path params 3) so this is the only way in pure javaee?

Comment: It's not a servlet. It's just a class that is called by the Jersey Servlet (which is `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`) to handle the appropriate requests

Comment: one of the reason that I switched from spring to javaee pure was that spring made objects while java ee makes threads of servlets. the later is fast. if thats the same case with jax-rs, its not a optimal choice.?

Comment: I don't know the details of how the controllers are handled at that level, but the documentation should be helpful. However I seriously doubt that you would run into performance problems in controllers using Spring or Jersey. The overhead of hitting a DB or some external service is so much larger than the overhead of handling controllers by the container, that it should be a non-issue